# PHP myslqli query() returning 1

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am referencing this php file from the index and it's already successfully connected to the mysql server. Below is my code, it always returns one. What I would like it to do is find the record in the table with id 2 (Primary Key) and find the element in that record under the "thumb" field. This contains a "VARCHAR" with a path to an image and I'd like this path to be output under a h3 tag (For testing). Please help, the only reason I think it's behaving like this is because there is only one record with and id equal to 2 - Thus, outputting the 1 for number of records rather than the actual info

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM software WHERE id = 2";
if ($result = $db->query($query)) {
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "<h3>". $result ."</h3>";
    }
    else {
        die($db->error);
    }
}
else {
    echo "<h2>No results</h2>";
}
?>
```

Please excuse the untidiness of this code :)

Comment: `$result` is a result HANDLE. it's not the data you queried for. you need to FETCH that row so you can output the actual data. and note that a query which returns 0 rows is NOT a failure. an empty result set is a perfectly valid result that just happens to be empty, no different than "how many invisible pink unicorns are standing on the street corner".

Comment: learn mysql_fetch_array();

Comment: @meh please, mysqli_fetch_array()! http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that:

```
$row = $result->fetch_object();
echo '<h3>'.$row->thumb.'</h3>';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `$result` is the object returned by the query.
As per [the documentation,](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), it returns *TRUE* (1) if the query was successful or *FALSE* (0) if unsuccessful.

In your case your query was successful, therefore it returns 1, which is TRUE.

```
"Returns FALSE on failure." ... "For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE."
```